# Built a PC some months ago, facing automatic shutdown, temperature issue?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, cooling, temperature, overheating

I built a PC some months ago, it worked fine, but now it's summer time and temperature is 45 °C here in Jaipur, India. When I start playing BF3 after 20-25 minutes my UPS starts beeping and system turns off automatically. When I touch the CPU case it's very hot. This is the report of my system taken after a sudden shutdown (Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur95U.jpg Text: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=b4DrfyYx). And here is the report after playing BF3 for 20 minutes, when UPS started beeping I noted this down (Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ2xD.jpg Text: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=TU198LyC). Please see this report and let me know is the temperature too much high? What should I do about it?

PS: This could be a voltage issue in my area, or an issue with the UPS (I bought this about 15 days ago) but I want to know whether the temperature of my system is fine or not? If not I'll buy a better cooling fan or a better UPS.

CPU: AMD FX-8350

PSU: Corsair VS550 550 Watt

GPU: Sapphire Radeon HD 7850 2GB GDDR5

UPS: 600va

Note: I found that if I don't use UPS my CPU doesn't shutdown automatically, so it means UPS is not able to provide enough voltage to GPU while playing high-end games. But still I want to know about the heating. Is the tempture fine or should I be worried and take some immediate actions?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to identify the beeping code, the pattern of the beeps represent a specific issue. Here's a link to help you find it

> http://www.biosflash.com/e/bios-beeps.htm

From the logs you posted I'm pretty sure that is an overheating issue you're facing, chipsets usually have the max temperature limit set around 110°C, when it is reached the PC shuts down to prevent damages.

I would suggest you to clean your case and fans, if the problem persist you should add an additional fan.

Answer (score 0):

You are overloading the UPS, that beeping it's making it's probably noting this. Search in the manual for the beeping code.

Moreover that UPS seems small, you have to multiply the VA * 0.6 to get the maximum load, in this case 600VA * 0.6 = 360w. Your PSU probably only loads 200-300w~ in normal use, but when playing a game it uses a lot more of watts (as the GPU and CPU go to 80%-100% load).

Temperatures seem normal for a PC on load, except that "Temperature #1: 86º", it's close to 90º and that's bad. Determine which one is reaching that temperature, and clean the HEAT SINK, and see how you can improve the air flow in that area.